# Download manager & Form Authetification in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, download-manager, form-authentication

We are providing our s/w for public downloads. Customers can download the s/w using the download manager using the below link its working fine.

www.example.com/downloads/setup.exe

Recently we have changed the process like if someone click on the "Setup.exe" for download we are taking them to login page (if they not signin).

Now, if we download using the Download Manager logon page.htm gets loaded instead of setup.exe. If any way to resolve this ?

Thanks,
Velus

Comment: as expected, download manager will download whatever it has the URL with it. try filtering in Download manager

Comment: What download manager are you using?